# Why doesn't the reg exp that works in regex101 dot com, does NOT work with grep nor with vim in Linux

Tags: regex, bash, vim, grep, regex-lookarounds

I have an ascii file in the format below:

```
gc_ab_cd               92641.48   25.2    5.12  9.20   0.00  gc_ht_t_gc_ab_cd
gc_ab_cd/reg              29.24    0.0    0.49  0.01   0.00  gc_ht_t_CHECK1_0
gc_ab_cd/reg/dff_in_gated 17.13    0.0    6.00  11.13  0.00  gc_ht_t_dff_en_in_WIDTH84_0
gc_ab_cd/reg/dff_in_send_gated 0.20  0.0  0.00   0.20  0.00  gc_ht_t_dff_in_WIDTH1_33
gc_ab_cd/reg/rd_rtn       11.42    0.0    4.20   7.22  0.00  gc_ht_t_gfx_2toN_WIDTH32_1
gc_ab_cd/regs          18583.88    5.1 2958.87  25.01  0.00  gc_ht_t_gc_ab_cd_regs
gc_ab_cd/tap_ch          431.51    0.1  144.83 150.05  0.00  gc_ht_t_gc_vm2_qe128
gc_ab_cd/tap_ch/throttle 136.63    0.0   77.33  59.30  0.00  gc_ht_t_gc_vm2__throttle
gc_ab_cd/vm2_dbg          22.79    0.0    0.00   0.00  0.00  gc_ht_t_gfx_dbg_mux_01
gc_ab_cd/vm2_dbg/bg_mux   22.79    0.0    9.90   4.80  0.00  gc_ht_t_gc_dbg_mux_4_1_01
gc_ab_cd/vm2_dbg/bg_mux/clk  0.20  0.0    0.00   0.20  0.00  gc_ht_t_clock
gc_ab_cd/vm2_dbg/bg__mux/flop_mux_flop 5.33 0.0 2.63 2.70 0.00 gc_ht_t_dbg_COUNT4_WIDTH8_0
```

I need to **grep 0 or 1 level of the hierarchy of the first field** in the above text, so that the output of the "grep" should print the below in the stdout

```
gc_ab_cd               92641.48   25.2    5.12  9.20   0.00  gc_ht_t_gc_ab_cd
gc_ab_cd/reg              29.24    0.0    0.49  0.01   0.00  gc_ht_t_CHECK1_0
gc_ab_cd/regs          18583.88    5.1 2958.87  25.01  0.00  gc_ht_t_gc_ab_cd_regs
gc_ab_cd/tap_ch          431.51    0.1  144.83 150.05  0.00  gc_ht_t_gc_vm2_qe128
gc_ab_cd/vm2_dbg          22.79    0.0    0.00   0.00  0.00  gc_ht_t_gfx_dbg_mux_01
```

I used the regexp https://regex101.com/r/D92KSP/1

But it gives only 3 matches below **(1 level of hierarchy in the first field)**, as can be seen in https://regex101.com/r/D92KSP/1

```
gc_ab_cd/reg              29.24    0.0    0.49  0.01   0.00  gc_ht_t_CHECK1_0
gc_ab_cd/regs          18583.88    5.1 2958.87  25.01  0.00  gc_ht_t_gc_ab_cd_regs
gc_ab_cd/tap_ch          431.51    0.1  144.83 150.05  0.00  gc_ht_t_gc_vm2_qe128
```

**Questions:**

[1] I'm NOT sure why the below line **(0 hierarchy in the first field)** is NOT being matched by the regexp in https://regex101.com/r/D92KSP/1

```
gc_ab_cd               92641.48   25.2    5.12  9.20   0.00  gc_ht_t_gc_ab_cd
```

[2] What should I do to modify the regexp  https://regex101.com/r/D92KSP/1 to match the line below

```
gc_ab_cd/vm2_dbg          22.79    0.0    0.00   0.00  0.00  gc_ht_t_gfx_dbg_mux_01
```

[3] I used the above regexp with "grep" and in the vim editor in Linux and it doesn't work there, though it works partially in regexp101.com. Don't know why?

Comment: Use `grep -E '^[^/]+(/[^/]+)?[[:blank:]]' file`

Comment: Please include the regular expression you're trying in the question (rather than just linking to something that shows it).

Comment: @M.NejatAydin can you please elaborate the reg exp you captured above. It works and is very elegant. I tried to understand the regexp but couldn't fully comprehend it. What does [[:blank:]] matches ?

Comment: @Mike `[:blank:]` is a character class expression which matches a horizontal spacing character, that is, in the POSIX locale,  either a tab or a space.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin - Thanks for your explanation. Quick question - How would the above reg exp would have changed, if I were to grep 0 or 1 or 2 levels of hierarchy in field 1. Implies abc  abc/def   abc/def/ghi . "?" worked well since we are looking for 0 or 1 levels of hierarchy. If it is 0 or 1 or 2, then "?" will NOT work.  In such a case, what would be the regular expression

Comment: `grep -E '^[^/]+(/[^/]+){0,2}[[:blank:]]' file`

Comment: Thanks @M.NejatAydin. I didn't know you can use "{0,2}" for 0/1/2. You seem to be a wizard of regular expressions. Thanks for your very elegant solutions

Answer (score 3):

regex101 and other such web sites will help you create/validate a regexp that works **on that web site**, don't assume it'll work anywhere else, especially the mandatory POSIX command-line tools like sed, grep, and awk as each tool uses specific regexp variants (BRE, ERE, and/or PCRE) with different arguments (e.g. `-E` to enable EREs in grep and sed, `-P` to enable PCREs in grep with some caveats), extensions (e.g. word boundaries, shortcuts, or back references), and limitations (e.g. delimiter chars). You have to learn which regexp variant with which extensions and limitations the version (e.g. GNU or BSD) of the tool you want to use supports.

In any case, any time you're talking about fields you should be using awk, not grep (or sed) since awk is the tool that separates input into fields. The following will work using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '$1 ~ "^[^/]*/?[^/]*$"' file
gc_ab_cd               92641.48   25.2    5.12  9.20   0.00  gc_ht_t_gc_ab_cd
gc_ab_cd/reg              29.24    0.0    0.49  0.01   0.00  gc_ht_t_CHECK1_0
gc_ab_cd/regs          18583.88    5.1 2958.87  25.01  0.00  gc_ht_t_gc_ab_cd_regs
gc_ab_cd/tap_ch          431.51    0.1  144.83 150.05  0.00  gc_ht_t_gc_vm2_qe128
gc_ab_cd/vm2_dbg          22.79    0.0    0.00   0.00  0.00  gc_ht_t_gfx_dbg_mux_01
```

or to search for a specific path depth by just setting a numeric variable on the command line:

```
$ awk -v n=2 '{key=$1} gsub("/","&",key)<n' file
gc_ab_cd               92641.48   25.2    5.12  9.20   0.00  gc_ht_t_gc_ab_cd
gc_ab_cd/reg              29.24    0.0    0.49  0.01   0.00  gc_ht_t_CHECK1_0
gc_ab_cd/regs          18583.88    5.1 2958.87  25.01  0.00  gc_ht_t_gc_ab_cd_regs
gc_ab_cd/tap_ch          431.51    0.1  144.83 150.05  0.00  gc_ht_t_gc_vm2_qe128
gc_ab_cd/vm2_dbg          22.79    0.0    0.00   0.00  0.00  gc_ht_t_gfx_dbg_mux_01

$ awk -v n=3 '{key=$1} gsub("/","&",key)<n' file
gc_ab_cd               92641.48   25.2    5.12  9.20   0.00  gc_ht_t_gc_ab_cd
gc_ab_cd/reg              29.24    0.0    0.49  0.01   0.00  gc_ht_t_CHECK1_0
gc_ab_cd/reg/dff_in_gated 17.13    0.0    6.00  11.13  0.00  gc_ht_t_dff_en_in_WIDTH84_0
gc_ab_cd/reg/dff_in_send_gated 0.20  0.0  0.00   0.20  0.00  gc_ht_t_dff_in_WIDTH1_33
gc_ab_cd/reg/rd_rtn       11.42    0.0    4.20   7.22  0.00  gc_ht_t_gfx_2toN_WIDTH32_1
gc_ab_cd/regs          18583.88    5.1 2958.87  25.01  0.00  gc_ht_t_gc_ab_cd_regs
gc_ab_cd/tap_ch          431.51    0.1  144.83 150.05  0.00  gc_ht_t_gc_vm2_qe128
gc_ab_cd/tap_ch/throttle 136.63    0.0   77.33  59.30  0.00  gc_ht_t_gc_vm2__throttle
gc_ab_cd/vm2_dbg          22.79    0.0    0.00   0.00  0.00  gc_ht_t_gfx_dbg_mux_01
gc_ab_cd/vm2_dbg/bg_mux   22.79    0.0    9.90   4.80  0.00  gc_ht_t_gc_dbg_mux_4_1_01
```

Comment: "regex101 and other such web sites will help you create/validate a regexp that works **on that web site**" -- yes, but also no. In my experience with regex101 in particular, if it works for a specific engine (i.e. Javascript, Python, Java 8), it works in that language. You're right that it doesn't universally work, but it does work in the matching engine off the website as well. Neither Vimscript nor grep's flavors are supported by it, however, so you're right it (often) doesn't work in either of these particular engines; but saying it only works on the website is a bit of a stretch

Comment: @Zoe I didn't say it only works on  the website, I said don't **assume** it works anywhere else. That's the common problem we see with questions in this forum - people assuming that if a regexp works on regex101 it'll work in whatever other tool they want to use a regexp with.